# Flexbox wrap, choose what child drops to next line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It's possible to choose what child of flexbox should drop to the next line, instead of always dropping the last one?
Example:
Full-Size, no breaking:
[image: Full size, no breaking]

Default behavior, breaking the last one.
[image]

Desired behavior, breaking the div from the middle to the other line:
[image]

Is this possible using flexbox?

Comment: Have you checked out flex's `order` property?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Answer (score 0):

`column` can approximate this in case you need equal width elements

```css
.box {
  column-width:max(30vw,150px);
}

.box > div {
  padding:10px;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

/* I need those extra elements to have correct layout */
.box > i {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>A</div><i></i>
  <div>B</div><i></i>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have an entire layout working with flexbox, I didn't want to have to change the type of display and how the layout itself works.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: You can use the **`order: n;`** property to order flexed items and **`flex`** shorthand property to make **`b`** element full width with **`flex: 0 0 100%`** and then change the order to **`order: 2`**

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a, .b, .c {
  flex: 1;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .b {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to change the order only when it is necessary to break to another line, see my examples with the images.

Comment: @Diego Sorry, didn't understand the question properly. I edited the answer. I don't see any other way of doing it. Assuming you don't know the flexed element's width percentage, you can use media queries for different breakpoints when you desire that behavior.